# AutoFac not properly resolving by type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I have been trying to learn more about AutoFac and ran into a situation that didn't make sense to me.  I created a sample application to highlight my problem so forgive the odd sample.  Basically I am trying to resolve a interface by type, the sample application has a command that takes in a type of a sub command to run and then tries to resolve the subcommand.  I am able to resolve the subcommand in one technique but not the other.

Here is my application and Controller code

```
public interface ISubCommand
{
    void Run();
}

public class OneSubCommand : ISubCommand
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //fake do something
    }
}

public class TwoSubCommand : ISubCommand
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //fake do something
    }
}


public class TestCommand
{

    private readonly Type _type;

    public TestCommand(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public void Run()
    {

        //this works and subcommandLive gets to be an instance of OneSubCommand
        var subcommands = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEnumerable<ISubCommand>>();
        var subcommandLive = subcommands.Single(x => x.GetType().FullName == _type.FullName);

        //this does not work and subcommandNULL is NULL
        var subcommandNULL = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(_type);

        //do something

    }

}

public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        var command = new TestCommand(typeof(OneSubCommand));
        command.Run();

        return View();
    }

}
```

And here is the container code in my Global.asax.cs

```
//setup the container
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//make sure all sub commands get registered
builder.RegisterType<OneSubCommand>().As<ISubCommand>();
builder.RegisterType<TwoSubCommand>().As<ISubCommand>();

//build the container and set it as the default
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

As you can hopefully see from my comments in the code, when I get a list of SubCommands and then do a Single on the list I get an instance of the subcommand however when I try to get an instance by directly passing in the type, it returns null.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in AutoFac or something in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac requires every type to be explicitly registered before resolving the type, it does not support auto-wiring for concrete types out of the box.

You can manually register each command as `ISubCommand` and as its concrete type using `AsSelf()` when registering the types:

```
builder.RegisterType<OneSubCommand>()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<ISubCommand>();
builder.RegisterType<TwoSubCommand>()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<ISubCommand>();
```

There is another option using the [`AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/ResolveAnything/AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource.cs) feature which will allow the container to resolve any concrete type without having to explicitly wire it:

```
builder.RegisterType<OneSubCommand>()
       .As<ISubCommand>();
builder.RegisterType<TwoSubCommand>()
       .As<ISubCommand>();      
builder.RegisterSource(
       new Autofac.Features.ResolveAnything.AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

I have created [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f1gMGE) so you can see both options in action.